# Trying to Upload App to Mac App Store, Invalid Binary?

Tags: ios, macos, cocoa, app-store

I'm getting ready to upload my Mac application to the Mac App Store, I've created the Application certificate and the installer certificate. When I go to validate my app, Xcode says the app has been validated and is ready to upload to the store. Every time I upload my app to iTunes Connect everything goes smoothly and the app uploads. Then the problem starts, in iTunes Connect my app state is listed as "Invalid Binary" and I receive an email from iTunes Connect saying my app was improperly signed. I really don't think I'm doing anything wrong. Right now, I have the project and the target in my app code signed, is this necessary or do I just need to sign one of them? Also, I've been having a strange issue that when I code sign the target my app builds but it doesn't run. It does not cause any error though. When only my project is signed, the app runs normally. I'm pretty confused on all of this so any help would be greatly appreciated. This is my first App Store submission so I'm excited to get an app up for sale.

Thanks for your time,

Sam

Edit: Just tried uploading the app with application loader. It uploaded to iTunes Connect but I still get the same invalid binary error. Also, I shared my archived application as a .pkg and tried to install it. I got an error saying that "This application cannot be installed on this computer". Any idea why this would happen?

Comment: When the signed app fails to run, is there any output in the system console?

Comment: Did you try cleaning after code signing?

Comment: You would have received the mail from apple for stating "Invalid binary"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a:

```
codesign -dvvv *.app
```

on an app bundle directory from the Terminal command-line to see how the app you are trying to upload is signed.

Any Target setting overrides the identical Project setting for that target build.  You should use a different build configuration for Distribution than for Release or Debug and running the app.