# iTunes Connect Reports "Invalid Binary" for Mac App

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, app-store, app-store-connect

I am trying to submit my first application to the Mac App Store.  I have setup the signing certificates on my computer, as well as setting up the application in iTunes connect.  Xcode allows me to produce an archive of my app, and even export a signed pkg file.  Both Application Loader and Xcode say that my binary passes "validation", but shortly after uploading my app to iTunes connect it is reported to have an "Invalid Binary." I read on Apple's [iTunes Approval Process](http://developer.apple.com/appstore/mac/resources/approval/) page some reasons why this might happen:

> Appears when a binary is received through Application Loader, has been processed, but your binary is invalid. Examples of an invalid binary are: your binary icon does not meet our requirements, you have placed the payload directory at the wrong level in the .app wrapper, you attempted to use a non-increasing CFBundleVersion, etc.

Unfortunately I am not receiving an email when this error occurs, and nothing is telling me what the problem is.  I am kind of hoping that Xcode would tell me if I signed my binary wrong in the "Validate" stage, but I may be wrong.

My question here is: **why might iTunes connect be reporting an "Invalid Binary"** and **how on earth can I fix it?**

EDIT: I have taken some screenshots of my project's configuration settings, and of iTunes connect:

- [iTunes connect app page](http://aqnichol.com/imgbay/images/1315324504.png)
- [Application in the Archive list](http://aqnichol.com/imgbay/images/1315324518.png)
- [Entitlements plist](http://aqnichol.com/imgbay/images/1315324532.png)
- [Code signing settings](http://aqnichol.com/imgbay/images/1315324600.png)
- [Info.plist](http://aqnichol.com/imgbay/images/1315324633.png)
- [Build settings (architectures, etc).](http://aqnichol.com/imgbay/images/1315324686.png)

Comment: google may be your friend (as well as developer.apple.com and discussions.apple.com) as there are myriad reports of this same issue

Comment: I have found many people having this same problem, and have tried many solutions.  If I find anything else I will certainly post it here.

Comment: The whole signing process is rather hard to fathom - and solving problems is worse. I'm sure somebody at apple understands how it all works, but the error quotient tells me that regular dev's are lost when these things pop up :(

Comment: What version number does Xcode show in its About panel?

Comment: I am running version 4.1, build 4B110.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trying to Upload App to Mac App Store, Invalid Binary?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7231381/trying-to-upload-app-to-mac-app-store-invalid-binary)

Answer (score 1):

You most likely are trying to submit a build that has the same version number as an earlier build. All builds that you upload to iTunes connect must have different version numbers. For example: Joe submits his first build of his app to iTunes connect as version 1.0, next time he submits he must change the version to 1.1 or any other higher value.